# Aligning layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am new at QGIS and am having a problem aligning layers. Possibly I just don't understand how projection works.

I have two layers:

1. GPS waypoints collected in a GPS UTM zone 55N
2. Polygon shapefile from ArcGIS CRS Guam 1963

The project CRS is EPSG:3857

The background is OpenStreetMap from the OpenLayers plugin and it does align correctly with the GPS UTM layer.

I have tried to save as the layers into what I thought was the correct CRS but I can't get them to line up. Below is the result.

[image]

What steps do I need to take to align these two layers?

Comment: Is Guam 1963 compatible with WGS? It uses Clarke 1866 spheroid which should require a transformation matrix to WGS84 spheroid. I'm not an expert on this CRS but I'd say that's where your problem is. Try to get your data in WGS84/DD or WGS84/UTM 55 North instead of Guam 1963 (ArcGis has a transformation for Clarke to WGS84).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way to accomplish this with QGIS?

Comment: I do not know about QGIS, this sort of datum transformation is not something that I do often... can you request a resupply of the data in UTM?

Comment: Convert your location to a single projection using PosGIS ST_SetSRID or ST_Transform (just read their behavior carefully) and work with the converted geodata on